# Reshaping then collapsing dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr, reshape2

Struggling to convert my messy, unequal-lengthed `data.frame` from a wide table to a long table, then collapsing (summarising) for the new variable. At the moment it looks like this, with `Gene` as one variable, and `GO_terms` as one variable containing multiple, comma-separated values:

```
Gene            GO_terms                        
AA1006G00001    GO:0098655, GO:0008643, GO:0005351, GO:0005886, GO:0016021      
AA100G00001     GO:0098655, GO:0009944, GO:0009862, GO:0010075, GO:0010014, GO:0009855, GO:0010310
AA100G00002     GO:0098655, GO:0008643, GO:0005886
```

First step I want to do, is convert to "long" format, so it looks like this:

```
Gene            GO_terms 
AA1006G00001    GO:0098655
AA1006G00001    GO:0008643
AA1006G00001    GO:0005351
AA1006G00001    GO:0005886
AA1006G00001    GO:0016021
AA100G00001     GO:0001666
AA100G00001     GO:0009944
AA100G00001     GO:0009862
AA100G00001     GO:0010075
AA100G00001     GO:0010014
AA100G00001     GO:0009855
AA100G00001     GO:0010310
AA100G00002     GO:0008270
AA100G00002     GO:0005634
AA100G00002     GO:0005886
AA100G00003     GO:0005488
AA100G00003     GO:0005634
```

Then, I wish to reorganise this `data.table` by switching the two variables, in that it is collated as follows:

```
GO_terms    Genes
GO:0005351  AA1006G00001        
GO:0005886  AA1006G00001,   AA100G00002 
GO:0008643  AA1006G00001,   AA100G00002 
GO:0009855  AA100G00001     
GO:0009862  AA100G00001     
GO:0009944  AA100G00001     
GO:0010014  AA100G00001     
GO:0010075  AA100G00001     
GO:0010310  AA100G00001     
GO:0016021  AA1006G00001        
GO:0098655  AA1006G00001,   AA100G00001,      AA100G00002
```

Variable containing genes can be within one column (with comma-separated values), or in multiple columns.

Anyone able to offer `tidyr`, `reshape2`, or `dplyr` solutions please?

EDIT: The `dput()` table is:

```
structure(list(`Gene    ` = c("AA1006G00001\t", "AA100G00001\t", 
"AA100G00002\t"), `GO_terms                     ` = c("GO:0098655, GO:0008643, GO:0005351, GO:0005886, GO:0016021\t\t", 
"GO:0098655, GO:0009944, GO:0009862, GO:0010075, GO:0010014, GO:0009855, GO:0010310", 
"GO:0098655, GO:0008643, GO:0005886")), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(`Gene   ` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `GO_terms                        ` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector"))), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? at what point are you sticking? I think SO is full of answers to each of your part-problems.

Comment: Can you post that first data frame as it actually is, like with `dput`? That would be more helpful since you're dealing with issues of how it's structured that we won't get from copying & pasting text

Comment: @AndreElrico I tried separating the GO_terms first by columns, then tried melt() using the `Gene` variable. The result wasn't right and had many blank values (because my GO_terms are of unequal length?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are doing some GO analysis. You can try `inverseList` from `topGO` (one of the most popular R packages for GO analysis in Bioconductor):

```
library(topGO)

gene.to.go <- strsplit(gsub('\t', '', df$GO_terms), ', ', fixed = TRUE)
names(gene.to.go) <- gsub('\t', '', df$Gene)

go.to.gene <- inverseList(gene.to.go)

data.frame(GO_term = names(go.to.gene), Genes = sapply(go.to.gene, paste0, collapse = ', '),
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE, row.names = NULL)

#       GO_term                                  Genes
# 1  GO:0005351                           AA1006G00001
# 2  GO:0005886              AA1006G00001, AA100G00002
# 3  GO:0008643              AA1006G00001, AA100G00002
# 4  GO:0009855                            AA100G00001
# 5  GO:0009862                            AA100G00001
# 6  GO:0009944                            AA100G00001
# 7  GO:0010014                            AA100G00001
# 8  GO:0010075                            AA100G00001
# 9  GO:0010310                            AA100G00001
# 10 GO:0016021                           AA1006G00001
# 11 GO:0098655 AA1006G00001, AA100G00001, AA100G00002
```

In fact, it would be easier to operate on the data if you import the GO mapping file with `readMappings` in `topGO`.

Comment: Thanks @mt1022! You're right – I am doing some GO analysis. I've imported the data with `readMappings`, and subsequently inverted it using `inverseList`. It doesn't seem to want to export as a table. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: Ah, reassigned the new inverted object to a `data.table`! Thanks a lot for your help @mt1022!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tidyr and dplyr solution:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

#allow up to seven Genes per GO_term if there is more increase the letters expression
long<-df %>% separate(GO_terms, into=paste0("a", 1:100), sep=", ", extra="merge") %>% 
  gather( key="key", value="GO_terms", -Gene)

#filter data frame, remove the NA and keep the desired columns
long<-long[!is.na(long$GO_terms), c("Gene", "GO_terms")]

final<-long %>% group_by(GO_terms) %>% summarize( Gene=toString(Gene) )
```

Comment: Thanks, @Dave2e. Strangely, this method yields 5963 unique GO_terms, while @mt1022's method of inverting the `Mappings` file in `TopGo` yields 5994 unique GO_terms. Odd... Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, sure, I only uploaded a tiny portion of the `data.table` for the purposes of SO! Changing the `into=letters` argument to `1:100` (I know my max number of GO_terms is 56) still yields the same number.

Comment: @WaheedArshad  56 elements, I completely under estimated that one. I edited the code above to allow for up to 100 different GO_terms.  The previous version would only accept the first 26.

Comment: You're a star, @Dave2e! Thanks a lot – much appreciated!